# If $f,g\in \mathcal{S}$, then $(f\ast g)^{(n)} = f^{(n)}\ast g = f\ast g^{(n)}$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I want to prove that:

> If $f,g\in \mathcal{S}$, then $(f\ast g)^{(n)} = f^{(n)}\ast g = f\ast g^{(n)}$

This is pretty much obvious if one knows that the differentiation can "enter the integral":

$$
     \frac{d}{dx} (f\ast g)(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int f(x-y)g(y)\,dy = \int  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x-y)g(y)\,dy
$$

(and then induction).

So this seems to be a job for the Leibniz integral theorem. However, I do not see how to apply it in this case.

Comment: What's $\mathcal{S}$? If you correctly prove that you can differentiate under the integral sign then it would be ok, also, can you write down what's $f*g$?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif It is the Schwartz space. And I think I did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts:
\begin{align}
(f'*g)(x) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(y) g(x-y) \, dy = \int u \,dv = uv - \int v\,du \\
\text{where } & u = g(x-y) \text{ and } dv = f'(y)\,dy \\
\text{so that } & du = -g'(x-y) \, dy \text{ and } v = f(y) \\[12pt]
& =uv - \int v\,du = \left. g(x-y) f(y) \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right|_{y\,;=\,-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\Big(-g'(x-y)\,dy\Big) \\[10pt]
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) g'(x-y)\, dy = (f*g')(x).
\end{align}

**Postscript:** I see that there is a bit more to the question than showing that $f'*g=f*g'.$ It was also desired to show that those are equal to $(f*g)'.$ If one knows about generalized functions such as "Dirac's" delta function $\delta,$ one can say that $\delta*f=f$ and then since $\delta'*f = \delta * f' = f',$ one can then say
$$
f'*g = (\delta'*f)*g = \delta'*(f*g) = (f*g)'.
$$
Without the theory of the delta function, there's further work to do.

Comment: Simple and useful. Great!

Answer (score 3):

When convolving elements of $\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$ you are allowed to differentiate under the integral sign. Indeed
$$
\frac{1}{h}\int_{\mathbb R} \big(f(x+h-y)-f(x-y)\big)g(y)\,dy-\int_{\mathbb R} f'(x-y)g(y)\,dy\\=\frac{1}{h}\int_{\mathbb R} \big(f(x+h-y)-f(x-y)-hf'(x-y)\big)g(y)\,dy \\=\frac{1}{h}\int_{\mathbb R}\int_0^h\big(f'(x-y+t)-f'(x-y)\big)\,g(y)\,dy\,dt\\=\frac{1}{h}\int_{\mathbb R}\int_0^h \int_0^t f''(x-y+s) g(y)\,dy\,dt\,ds \\ =\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h \int_0^t (\,f''*g)(x+s)\,dt\,ds
$$
Clearly
$$
\left|\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h \int_0^t (\,f''*g)(x+s)\,dt\,ds\,\right|\le \|\,f''*g\|_\infty\cdot\frac{1}{h}\cdot h\cdot h=h\to 0.
$$

Comment: Could you say the name of the result or theorem that you used in order to conclude that this suffices for prove differentiability under the integral sign? It does not seem to be Leibniz rule.

Comment: I did not use any Theorem other than the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: $$\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx=f(b)-f(a).$$

Comment: Oh, forget it. I now understand what you did. Great!